# Is there a possibility to add an animation created by Adobe After Effects to a react native project? If yes, than how is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, effects

So, basically what I need to do is to import a custom animation which I created in Adobe After Effects and make it work as an animation in react native. Is there a method to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native

I've never used it with React Native, but web version works perfectly fine (https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web).